# Bootstrap Modal 内にAjaxで表示

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

`#mymodal`の`.modal-body`内に`phpfile.php`で呼び出された内容を表示したいのですが、以下のコードではうまくいきません。
modalは出て来るし、ajaxでなければ表示されるので、modal内へのページの読み込みができていないと言うことでしょうが…。

```
function addCart(id){
    $('#mymodal .modal-body').load("phpfile.php", $("#" + id).serialize(), function () {
        $('#mymodal').modal('show');
    });
```

どなたかご指摘頂けると、助かります。

Answer (score 1):

phpfile.phpが　POSTでフォームコントロールのデータを受けているなら、第２引数は文字列では無く、オブジェクトを第２引数で渡さないと phpfile.phpは結果データを返さないのではないかと思います。（.serialize()は文字列を返すのでGET渡しになる）

以下にオブジェクト渡し（POST送信）の例

```
$('#hoge .fuga').load("piyo.php", {data1: 1, data2: 2},function(data){console.log(data)});
```